# Why ArrayList in C# is not safe?

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I have heard lately that `ArrayList` from `System.Collections` is not safe, what is the problem? 
Safe is: that may have errors, or may have an unwanted behavior.

Comment: Did you mean "type safe"?

Comment: What do you mean by safe? Type safe? Thread safe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's Wrong with an ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326599/whats-wrong-with-an-arraylist)

Comment: that may have errors, or may have an unwanted behavior

Comment: Side note: Darin and Tim gave you good answer for on of 2 question you should have asked "is ArrayList thread safe" or "is ArrayList type safe". Your current way of asking sounds like you expect this class to have errors in implementation: "may have errors", which is not what answered in the accepted answer. Next time try to define your terms better and possibly give link to definition.

Comment: I did not know the term type-safe nor thread-safe concept. as I can I specify?, if do not know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not safe because they are not strongly typed. This means that you do not know at compile time the types of objects that could be stored inside. Also you will need to cast to the actual types meaning that you will get errors only at runtime. You should instead use the generic and strongly typed equivalent [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Take a look at the following example where you need to cast the result obtained from the ArrayList to the actual type:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(123);
int element = (int)list[0];
```

Things could get terribly wrong if you cast to the wrong type and your program will crash only at runtime.

Whereas with the `List<T>` you don't need this cast and you get compile-time safety:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(123);
int element = list[0];
```

Now if by *safety* you mean thread safety (in contrast to type safety) then this is an entirely different thing. Both `ArrayList` and `List<T>` are not thread-safe classes. This means that if for example you attempt to read from the collection from one thread while another thread is modifying it, you might get an exception or corrupted data. In .NET 4.0, [thread safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) have been introduced.

Answer (score 9):

It's not strongly typed nor is it inherently thread-safe*. There are better alternatives which support strong typing, such as `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

An `ArrayList` doesn't support compile-time type checking, can introduce boxing/unboxing overhead, and in general is more messy to work with. It was introduced prior to generics, which eliminate the aforementioned issues.

- [Generic List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [Thread-safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)

<sup>*In the interest of accuracy, ArrayList does expose a `Synchronized` property which provides a level of thread safety ([see notes at end of article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It's unsafe because the following fails at run-time:

```
myArrayList.Add(new Banana());
Airplane obj = (Airplane)myArrayList[0];
```

The compiler cannot detect that you're trying to use a Banana as an Airplane, since ArrayList takes and returns only `object`s, and everything in .NET is an `object`.

`ArrayList` has essentially been replaced by `System.Collections.Generics.List(T)` since .NET 2.0; it is a more strongly-typed replacement and doesn't allow this kind of mistake.