# Simplest way of calculating the number of working days using delegates in c#?

Tags: c#, delegates

Here is my simple code which I used delegates and lambda expression to get the working days from the given start date and end date.

My friend says he can write the whole program in one line. How would I do that?

```
public delegate void GetWorkingDays(DateTime x,DateTime y);
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 3);
        var dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 10, 3);
        System.Collections.ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        GetWorkingDays d = (d1, d2) =>
        {
            while (d1.Date < d2.Date) 
            {
                if(d1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                {
                    d1 = d1.AddDays(2);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                   Console.Write(d1.Day + "  ");
                    d1 = d1.AddDays(1);
                }
            } 
        };
        d(dt1, dt2);
    }
};
```

Comment: "My friend says he can write the whole program in one line." Let him answer your Question :)

Comment: I am a beginner in c#, So im posting my question here, So that i can learn new things.

Comment: Firstly, is there a reason you chose to go with a delegate instead of just a method? You are adding overhead here that is not needed. Unless the aim is to learn to work with delegates of course.

Comment: He actually told me that using delegates you can write in one line, so i just gave a try...

Comment: The solution of your friend is certainly wrong. It is quite difficult in reality since you do normally not only not work at Sat/Sun but also at public holidays which are country dependant. To make it even more complex public holidays are added and removed from time to time by new laws. You need some up to date database which does contain the public non working days if you want to calculate for the current year or historical years the number of working days. Then you need to subtract your vacation days and write all code in one line. Then check if your editor support such wide lines.

Comment: I understand, but IM looking to print the days which which doesnt follow on Saturdays and sundays...

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how you could do it in one line since it will take one line to define the delegate and one line to call the delagate at a minimum.  But this is one line to get the days that are weekdays and count them.

```
GetWorkingDays d = (dateFrom, dateTo) =>
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int)dateTo.Subtract(dateFrom).TotalDays + 1)
            .Select(x => dateFrom.AddDays(x))
            .Count(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
Console.Writeline("Number of Weekdays is {0}",d(dateFrom, dateTo));
```

Or

```
 var days = Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int)d2.Subtract(d1).TotalDays + 1)
            .Select(x => d1.AddDays(x))
            .Count(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: For single return statement you don't need curly braces & return statement.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not answer your question, it's really important to tell you that you shouldn't be doing this at all, for two reasons.

1. Writing readable code is very very important, and your existing code is as good as it can get. A complex one-liner will not only make it less readable but also make debugging harder. Overall maintenance is a nightmare.
2. You aim to bring a side effect rather than return a value after some computation. In other words your delegate returns `void`. A Linq style query is not the way to go here.

And two suggestions:

1. I saw `ArrayList` in your code. It is criminal to use it since .NET 2. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326599/whats-wrong-with-an-arraylist) You will be hailed as a hero if you change it to a `List<T>`. If your friend is smart he should help you with such basic things rather than being pedantic.
2. A name that starts with `Get...` is not a good name for a method (or a delegate) that returns (gets) nothing (`void`). I would call it `WorkingDaysPrinter` or so.

---

Just for the sake of it, your answer would be something like:

```
WorkingDaysPrinter p = (d1, d2) => Enumerable.Range(0, d2.Subtract(d1).Days)
                                             .Select(x => d1.AddDays(x))
                                             .Where((x, i) => i == 0 || x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                                             .ToList()
                                             .ForEach(x =>
                                              {
                                                  if (x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                                                      Console.WriteLine();
                                                  else
                                                      Console.Write(x.Day + " ");
                                              });
```

It's *slightly* better to write the query separately and then run a separate `foreach`:

```
WorkingDaysPrinter p = (d1, d2) => 
{
    var query = Enumerable.Range(0, d2.Subtract(d1).Days)
                          .Select(x => d1.AddDays(x))
                          .Where((x, i) => i == 0 || x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    foreach (var day in query)
    {
        if (x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            Console.WriteLine();
        else
            Console.Write(x.Day + " ");
    });
}
```

---

By the looks of it I think it would be better if your delegate returns a list of working days. Something like:

```
public delegate IEnumerable<DateTime> WorkingDaysGetter(DateTime x, DateTime y);

WorkingDaysGetter g = (d1, d2) => Enumerable.Range(0, d2.Subtract(d1).Days)
                                            .Select(x => d1.AddDays(x))
                                            .Where(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
foreach (var day in g(dt1, dt2))
{
    Console.Write(x.Day + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = Enumerable
        .Range(1, (int)y.Subtract(x).TotalDays)
        .Select(x => to.AddDays(x))
        .Count(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: My question was not to get count... But all the days which doesnt fall on Saturday and Sunday,between the two dates given.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetWorkingDays getWorkDays = (d1, d2) =>
    Enumerable.Range(1, (int)(dt2 - dt1).TotalDays)
        .Select(d => dt1.AddDays(d))
        .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(d => Console.Write(d.Day + " "));
```