# C# Arraylist into a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with C# in a web form.  I setup an arraylist.  I have a button that add user input in a text box to the arraylist.  I'm using the += to print out the arraylist to a label.  I'm having trouble just printing out the new entry to the exisiting list.  Each time I add, it prints out the whole list again.  I understand why it's doing that but just can't wrap my fried brain at the moment how to fix the code so it adds a new entry to the list without repeating the whole list.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    ArrayList itemList = new ArrayList();
    itemList.Add("red");
    itemList.Add("blue");
    itemList.Add("green");
    itemList.Add(TextBox1.Text);

    foreach (object item in itemList)
    {
        Label1.Text += item + "<br />";
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use the obsolete `ArrayList` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3326606/932418). Use a generic version of it, `List<T>`.

```
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
itemList.Add("red");
itemList.Add("blue");
itemList.Add("green");
itemList.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

Now you can update your label with a single line...

```
Label1.Text = string.Join("<br />", itemList);
```

**EDIT**

> Unfortunately, for this example I have to use an arraylist

You can still do it with one line

```
Label1.Text = string.Join("<br />", itemList.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for this example I have to use an arraylist.

Comment: Thank you everyone all the examples work.  I having another problem with keeping the previous entry in the arrayList.  I think I have to declare a string array and store it in there but not sure, doing the trial and error thing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Just add Label1.Text = "" before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the loop do this:

```
Label1.Text = string.Empty;
```