# Is it possible to create a list where two different classes can be added?

Tags: c#

I have tried to add two classes (car and van) in an arraylist but seems like the list is defined by the first class (car) and when trying to add the other class (van) I get the **runtime error**

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'CarBroker.Car' to type 'CarBroker.Van'.

I believe the error is caused by the arraylist is defined when creating the first entry of the type 'Car' and when trying to add a different type 'Van' the error occurs.

Is there another list that can be used instead?

```
public class List // Global ArrayList to store car data
{ public static ArrayList vehicle = new ArrayList(); }
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Car car = new Car();
    car.SetVehicleData();
    car.SetOwnerData();

    List.vehicle.Add(car);

    Van van = new Van();
    van.SetVehicleData();
    van.SetCompanyData();

    List.vehicle.Add(van);

    Admin a1 = new Admin();
    a1.ListAll();

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

When running my ListAll() method the ideal output would be first list entry with the class 'car' and the second entry with the class 'van'

Instead I get the error mentioned above.

Anyone that can help me on the way using the right list or another function? I am attending a basic C# class so I am not that advanced :)

Comment: do `Car` and `Van` share an interface/base class other than `Object`? if so use `List<YourBase>`

Comment: Create a base class Vehicle and have Van and Car inherit the Vehicle class.

Comment: You have various options. Either you make the two classes inherit from a common base type and make the list contain that base type, or you could make one of the types, such as car, the base type for the other. You can also make both types implement a common interface and make the list out of that interface, or you can make the list hold just `object` elements, which can hold anything.

Comment: As an aside, read  [What's Wrong with an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3326599/1364007).

Comment: No, the list will preserve your new properties, but when you iterate through the list you have to test the objects. For example:

         foreach (Vehicle vehicle in List)
         {
             if (vehicle is Car)
             {
                Car car = vehicle as Car
                 car.customProp
             }
             if (vehicle is Van)
             {
                 Van van = vehicle as Van
                 van.VanCustomProp
             } 
         }

Comment: Thanks all for the help. It works with your help using a generic List<T>. Now I just need to snatch the different types `CarBroker.Car` and ´CarBroker.Van` from the list to use it for an unique ID generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList`, use generic `List<T>` and you will be able to do that as long as     both classes inherit from the same base class. 
Polymorphism.

Create a new `List<BaseClass>`. We assume that `Car` and `Van` inherit from the `BaseClass`. Then

```
List.Add(Car)
List.Add(Van)
```

When you iterate through the list you have to test the objects. For example:

```
  foreach (Vehicle vehicle in List) 
  { 
        if (vehicle is Car car) 
        { 
            car.customProp 
        } 
        if (vehicle is Van van) 
        { 
           van.VanCustomProp 
        } 
   }
```

Comment: Hi Sinatr, the classes `Van` and `Car` inherit variables from a superclass or upperclass called `Vehicle` but I have added new variables in `Van` and `Car`. Will List<T> ignore the differences in the object added to the list?

Comment: @JesperLeviHemmingsen  No, the list will preserve your new properties, but when you iterate through the list you have to test the objects. For example: foreach (Vehicle vehicle in List) { if (vehicle is Car) { Car car = vehicle as Car car.customProp } if (vehicle is Van) { Van van = vehicle as Van van.VanCustomProp } }

Comment: posting code here is exhausting

Comment: select code, press Ctrl+K.

Comment: If you need to check whether a vehicle is a car or a van from the list then you probably have code smell

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do what you're trying to do you'll need a common interface between Car and Van; You can do this 2 ways via a base class or an interface:

```
public class Vehicle {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IVehicle {
    void SetVehicleData(string data);
    void SetOwnerData(string data);
}
```

Then your car and van will inherit those interfaces:

```
public class Car : Vehicle, IVehicle {
    public void SetOwnerData(string data) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetVehicleData(string data) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Van : Vehicle, IVehicle {
    public void SetOwnerData(string data) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetVehicleData(string data) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
        var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

        var car = new Car() { Name = "Rover" };
        car.SetOwnerData("data");
        car.SetVehicleData("Rover 75");

        vehicles.Add(car);

        var van = new Van() { Name = "Transit" };
        van.SetOwnerData("data");
        van.SetVehicleData("Transit Van");

        vehicles.Add(van);
```

If your `SetOwner` and `SetVehicle` behave in the same way then put this behaviour in your base class:

```
public class Vehicle : IVehicle {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OwnerData { get; set; }
    public string VehicleData { get; set; }
    public void SetOwnerData(string data) {
        OwnerData = data;
    }

    public void SetVehicleData(string data) {
        VehicleData = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try out the solutions. I have a base class named `Vehicle` already, so perhaps I just need to modify my code a bit to get it to work!

Comment: In that case you just need to change line: `public static ArrayList vehicle = new ArrayList(); ` to be `public static List<Vehicle> vehicle = new List<Vehicle>();`